# Angular - Before Dynamic Ng-Include Template Loads, it Results In 404 for missing Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load a template into ng-include dynamically, but on page load, it triggers a 404 before loading it.  How can I wait until everything has loaded, and the $scope variables have been set, and then load the following template?

```
ng-include=" 'views/partials/'+ data.panels.a.content +'.html' "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ng-if around it

```
<div ng-if="data.panels.a.content">
    <div ng-include=" 'views/partials/'+ data.panels.a.content +'.html' "></div>
</div>
```